# How to convert APA style citations (Coley et al 2004) to IEEE format [1]?

Tags: academic-writing, citations, software, apa, microsoft-word

I have a journal article with citations in APA format (e.g. Coley et al 2004) and I need to convert them to the IEEE format (represented with numbers, such as [1]), which are then listed at the bottom of the document.

Is there a software that can do this automatically (any editor, Word, OpenOffice) or I have to do this manually reinserting them in Word through the Citations manager?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE and thanks for a question that is not like the ones we usually get.  Please check out our contest and add your question to the list.  https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/contest-ask-questions-earn-badges-win-prizes?cb=1

Answer (score 1):

I have never followed the IEEE style so I had to look it up.

The only way you can convert the style as far as I know is to do it manually.  You can use Word's citation/bibliography manager if you wish.  If IEEE style is not available in your copy of Word, there is an [IEEE Reference Style file available here](http://mikemurko.com/general/ieee-referencing-for-word-2007-2010).

You can of course type the references manually, which may or may not be quicker.  It depends on your experience.